# Issue saving node.js file on Mac with atom

Tags: node.js, macos, google-cloud-functions, atom-editor

I am trying to save a node.js file with Atom. When I hit cmnd-s I am hit with Unable to save file '/Users/myUsername/Desktop/fileName/filePath/index.js'

When I create a new file, I can successfully save it. However, the original file I am trying to save is giving me that error code. I have tried to clear the cache and update node-js but nothing is working for me. I am trying to deploy firebase functions in the terminal and it was working smoothly until it was not. Has anyone had this happen before?

Comment: `Unable to save file` is too generic. You probably need to close Node.js before saving the file.

Comment: @D.Pardal that is exactly the issue I am having. I don't know how to word or break it down any further than what it states. If I close the file, the code saves in the file, but when I try to deploy the firebase function in terminal, the error code I presented above shows.